# How can i start a session, destro and regenerate a new on

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am new to programing. Somebody please help me re-write this code.

Here is my code:

```
            <?php
            session_start();
            session_regenerate_id(true);
            $ses_id = session_id();
            
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            ?>
```

This is what i want to achieve is with the above code:

1. Start a session
2. Destroy the session after certain time if INACTIVE
3. After then, REGENERATE or start anew session.

I am writing a simple script that should start a session, then destroy the session if INACTIVE for a period of time, example 5 minutes.
Then regenerate a new session after destroying the old on.

Answer (score 1):

This could be like this

```
<?php
session_start();
if(((time() - $_SESSION['last_ative_time'])>300)){
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('location: ');
}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried it, but this is the error message it is displaying.

( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in on line 7

Comment: @Bubu are you serious? Did you even read the error message?

Comment: I had changed it at header define your header file.